# Whats the $L_2$ Norm in relation to Wavelets and functions?

Tags: wavelets

I have read that in order for a function to be a wavelet, it needs to fufull the L2 Norm property.
But I don't know what that is and there wasn't an explanation either. I know theres a L2 norm in relation to vectors, but that doesn't seam to be the same thing.
So what does it mean for a function to be L2 conform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While some context is missing, like what the domain of your function is, for a function $f$ to have bounded $L^2$ norm means that $\int_D |f(x)|^2 dx<\infty$.  The norm is induced by an inner product $\langle f, g \rangle = \int_D f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx$, and the collection of all functions with bounded $L^2$ norm on $D$ form a Hilbert space.  There is a lot of nice theory of Hilbert spaces, and all of this is standard when studying measure theory and functional analysis, so a book on measure theory might be a good starting place.

Comment: thanks, but what is the line ontop of g(x) for, also why does f(x) need to be absolute when  (-x)*(-x)=x*x?

Comment: Complex conjugation, in case you want to deal with complex valued functions instead of just real valued ones, in which case the absolute value becomes necessary because $|z|^2=z\overline z \neq z^2$ for complex numbers.

Comment: ah, thanks makes sense